# Cannot convert tuple data into int in python

Tags: python, integer

```
   I have function which reads a tuple from a .csv file.
```

Idk why but it is stored as a string and when I try to convert it into int it gives me error.

It first said,  `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','`
and when I tried converting it into a float and then to int, its giving me error `Cannot Convert into a string`

```
   try:
        data_black = pandas.read_csv("../../data/black_pieces_data.csv")
        dict_black = data_black.to_dict()

        pos = dict_black[f"pawn{i}"][0]   # here, pos is (1,0) for the 1st iteration

        row = int(pos[1])                 # This is being converted into int correctly
        col = int(float((pos[2])))        # I also tried col = int(pos[2]) and

                                          # it gave me ValueError saying I cannot to convert to Int.

        self.squares[row][col] = Square(row, col, Pawns("black"), "pawns")   # Don't foucs on this part.

    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showerror("Cannot Load", "There is no save file.\nCannot Load Game.")
    pass
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Look at what the error message is telling you.  It's very clear.  It's telling you that you passed the string `','` to `int()`, which resulted in an error.  So, stop passing `','` to `int()`.  Try examining the raw string.  Then figure out what you need to do to extract the fields.

Comment: @TomKarzes, I have given the input as `input[name] = (1,0), True` and it gave me the errors mentioned above. I was trying to extract (1,0) and now I have changed the input as following, `input[name] = 1, 0, True`. This seems to return everything as a string and I am able to convert the 1 and 0 into int now. Thanks for the suggest btw.